# Example to show that a bimonotonic function on a cartesian product of closed intervals on $\mathbb{R}$ need not be bounded.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I've come to a problem in a multivariate calculus book that I'm having trouble with.

Let $I$ and $J$ be closed and bounded intervals in $\mathbb{R}$. Give an example to show that a bimonotonic
function on $I \times J$ need not be bounded.

Here a function $f : \mathbb{R}^{2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is bimonotonically increasing if :
\begin{equation}
x_{1} \leq x_{2} \text{ and } y_{1} \leq y_{2} \Rightarrow f(x_{1},y_{2})+f(x_{2},y_{1}) \leq f(x_{1},y_{1}) + f(x_{2},y_{2})
\end{equation}
And a function is bimonotonically decreasing if :
\begin{equation}
x_{1} \leq x_{2} \text{ and } y_{1} \leq y_{2} \Rightarrow f(x_{1},y_{2})+f(x_{2},y_{1}) \geq f(x_{1},y_{1}) + f(x_{2},y_{2})
\end{equation}
A function is called bimonotonic if it is bimonotonically increasing or bimonotonically decreasing.

Can anyone come up with an example ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an easy example:

Let $f': I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be an unbounded function on the closed interval $I$, and let $$ f(x,y) := f'(x) \quad \forall x\in I, y \in J\,, $$
for some closed interval $J$.

Then $f$ is unbounded and bimonotonically increasing (and decreasing), because $$ f(x_1,y_2) + f(x_2,y_1) 
 = f'(x_1) + f'(x_2) = f(x_1,y_1) + f(x_2,y_2) \,.$$

Answer (score 0):

I saw this in one of the reference books I am using right now.

We define the function as,

*f(x,y)= xy*

Hence,

*$x_2y_2 + x_1 y_1 - x_1 y_2 - x_2 y_1 = (x_2 - x_1) (y_2 - y_1) \geq 0$*
which makes it bimonotonically increasing.

For bimonotonically decreasing, we can define the function as

*f(x,y) =  - xy*